# Preventing cache in html page displayed by SharePoint content editor web part

Tags: html, caching, sharepoint-2010

I'm using a content editor web part to pull/display a html file that lives in a SharePoint library, is there any way i can prevent the page (html or SharePoint) from caching?

I have tried the following in the html file with no luck:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this help you or not but..

Try to add ? at the end of your content link

Let me know if this help you or not.

Thanks